# Using themes between Magento editions

Tags: templates, php, magento

Is there a difference in themes for the Magento Community, Professional and Enterprise editions? If I develop a theme and test it using the Community edition, will it work on the other commercially available editions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise edition does come with it's own theme, but it is based on the Modern theme from Community.  Your problem in developing it only on Community is that you won't be able to predict the layout/format of Enterprise only features such as Gift Cards, etc.  You can make some reasonable assumptions, but no guarantees.

I would try to find an instance of EE that you can use to develop in, and then test in CE afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The system under the EE hood is the same that is in Magento 1.4 series and it will most definitely work to some level. What will not work and is used as default are the functionality that is not in CE edition.

Comment: Just for reference, the codebases of EE and CE are forked, and have been for some time now. Aside from crossports of bug fixes, there is no guarantee that any of the code development in CE comes across to EE.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, and your theme will not work without modification in both editions. Aside from bonus features (which you won't have in community), many of the standard libraries in Magento are not in sync between the two versions, so there is a marked difference in the way that some functions are handled.

Agree w/ Jon that you need to find an EE instance to test on.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme will mostly work on Enterprise and Pro editions, but there will be a lot of places with errors, lacking functionality and visual defects.

As a Magento Core developer I know the EE and Pro themes so I guarantee that :)